# Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, lit-element

When I execute `npm run dev` in the terminal build compilation was successful, however when I tried to access it in the browser I got the ff error.

#### Browser Console

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
EntryModuleNotFoundError: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/style-loader/index.js' in '/Users/user/Public/project-1/src/css'
    at moduleFactory.create (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1075)
    at factory (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401)
    at resolver (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130)
    at asyncLib.parallel (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224)
    at :8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830
    at :8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877
    at :8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830
    at done (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2925)
    at resolver.resolve (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:449)
    at doResolve (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213)
    at hook.callAsync (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44)
    at hook.callAsync (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (:8080/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285)
    at Object../src/css/bootstrap.css (log.js:59)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.0 (main.854fff77.js:13338)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
client:150 [WDS] Errors while compiling. Reload prevented.
errors @ client:150
client:159 ./src/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
EntryModuleNotFoundError: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/style-loader/index.js' in '/Users/user/Public/project-1/src/css'
    at moduleFactory.create (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1075:31)
    at factory (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22)
    at resolver (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21)
    at asyncLib.parallel (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22)
    at /Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at /Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at done (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2925:13)
    at resolver.resolve (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:449:23)
    at doResolve (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14)
    at hook.callAsync (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7)
    at hook.callAsync (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
errors @ client:159
client:159 ./src/css/fontawesome-all.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
EntryModuleNotFoundError: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/style-loader/index.js' in '/Users/user/Public/project-1/src/css'
    at moduleFactory.create (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1075:31)
    at factory (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22)
    at resolver (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21)
    at asyncLib.parallel (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22)
    at /Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at /Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at done (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2925:13)
    at resolver.resolve (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:449:23)
    at doResolve (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14)
    at hook.callAsync (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7)
    at hook.callAsync (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/Users/user/Public/project-1/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const loadPresets = require('./build-utils/loadPresets');
const assets = [
  {
    from: 'src/img',
    to: 'img/'
  }
];
const plugins = [
  new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: './src/index.html',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyJS: true
    }
  }),
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([...assets], {
    ignore: ['.DS_Store']
  })
];

module.exports = ({ mode, presets }) => {
  return webpackMerge(
    {
      mode,
      output: {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash:8].js'
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
          },
          {
            test: /\.(svg)$/,
            loader: ['file-loader']
          },
          {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
            loader: ['file-loader']
          },
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                    targets: '>1%, not dead, not ie 11'
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins,
    },
    loadPresets({ mode, presets })
  );
};
```

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback",
    "prod": "npm run webpack -- --env.mode production --env.presets serviceworker",
    "dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --env.mode development",
    "dev:sw": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --env.mode development  --env.presets serviceworker"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [
    "aslec",
    "home",
    "care",
    "aide",
    "admin",
    "landing-page"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@11ty/eleventy": "^0.10.0",
    "@11ty/eleventy-plugin-syntaxhighlight": "^3.0.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.5",
    "@open-wc/testing": "^2.5.10",
    "@open-wc/testing-karma": "^3.3.11",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.11",
    "@types/mocha": "^7.0.2",
    "acorn": "7.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "lit-analyzer": "^1.1.9",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.8.2",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "web-component-analyzer": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.4.3",
    "lit-element": "^2.3.1"
  }
```

Can someone pinpoint to me what I'd miss?

Comment: Can you check whether the `index.js` file is present on the root level?

Comment: `index.js` is present under src folder

Comment: I will now close this, it was all working but I was dumb, I didn't realize I was working on the wrong path. Sorry